# Full width li elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the list elements of this list full width. They had padding on them and when you hover on them the padding is coloured yellow.

The padding isn't filling up the whole ul block which is what I want it to do.

I have tried using different displays and making the width of the list element 100% but this doesn't work.

```css
.footer-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-navigation li {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-navigation a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
.footer-navigation a:hover {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fac900;
}
```

```html
<ul class="footer-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cookie Policy</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your anchors block level instead of inline. You can also add box-sizing so that they don't poke out and extend beyond the right edge:

```css
.footer-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-navigation li {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.footer-navigation a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
}
.footer-navigation a:hover {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fac900;
}
```

```html
<ul class="footer-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cookie Policy</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

actualy you padding isn't changing color to yellow on hovw.it is anchor tag. Change it to`li:hover` to change color of full li item.  Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbjz3eyh/)

```css
.footer-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-navigation li {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-navigation a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
.footer-navigation li:hover {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fac900;
}
```

```html
<ul class="footer-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cookie Policy</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<li>`s actually occupy full width of parent `<ul>`, the problem here is that you're applying the hover effect on the `<a>` links inside the `<li>`s not the `<li>`s themselves. `<a>`s are [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) they occupy the width of their text only.

you can solve this by applying `display: inline-block;` to the `<a>`s.

```css
.footer-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-navigation li {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.footer-navigation a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.footer-navigation a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fac900;
}
```

```html
<ul class="footer-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Cookie Policy</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're yellow background is showing on the `a` element. Your 'li`element **is** 100% width, but the highlight is showing on the`a` element, which is not 100% width.

Add this css:

```
.footer-navigation li:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #fac900;
}
```

and remove this:

```
.footer-navigation li:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #fac900;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/vj04zs2g/

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are styling the anchor element itself, which is by default an inline element. By simply changing your CSS :hover from targeting the  element to targeting the

element, you achieve the desired result.

Here is the changed CSS class, and a jsfiddle of what I mean:

```
.footer-navigation li:hover {
padding: 10px; 
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #fac900;
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/69ywk05b/

There are other improvements that can be made, for example:

- padding on both

  the color change on hover is lost when targeting

here is a more refactored version of your css:

```
.footer-navigation {
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0px;
}

.footer-navigation li {
    padding: 15px;
}

.footer-navigation a {
    color: #000000;
}
.footer-navigation li:hover {
    background-color: #fac900;
}

.footer-navigation li:hover a {
    color: #ffffff; 
}
```